# ComboBox DropDownStyle DropDownList : Change BackColor WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am making one app where I highlight currently focused controls.
For `TextBox` I use the `BackColor` property.

But in case of a `ComboBox` with `DropDownStyle = DropDownList`, `BackColor` does not seem to make it highlight.

Any suggestion(border etc?) on how can I make the controls Highlight in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 2):

As Reniuz said, you'll need to change the DrawMode properties.

Specifically, changing the **DrawMode** to **OwnerDrawFixed** will allow you to specify the BackColor.

## System.DrawMode

> **Normal** - All the elements in a control are drawn by the operating system and are of the same size.
>
> **OwnerDrawFixed** - All the elements in the control are drawn manually and are of the same size.
>
> **OwnerDrawVariable** - All the elements in the control are drawn manually and can differ in size.

See [System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change FlatStyle or DrawMode properties. But control will look a bit different. May be it will fit for you :)